# Trying to create cross fade for apostrophe-images when multiple images are selected

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to add a simple css transition on opacity when more than one photo is selected. Slideshow mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `apostrophe-images-widgets` widget player, which is the browser-side JavaScript that accompanies a widget, by following this tutorial but placing the code into your project level `/lib/modules/apostrophe-images-widgets/public/js/always.js`

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html#adding-a-java-script-widget-player-on-the-browser-side

In overriding this you'll have to do everything. The current images widget uses a jQuery plugin called `jquery-projector` https://github.com/punkave/jquery-projector but in overriding the player you can swap it out for another front-end slideshow plugin or write something custom.